# Pandas groupby: Nested loop fails with key error

Tags: python, pandas

I have CSV file with the following test content:

```
Name;N_D;mu;set
A;10;20;0
B;20;30;0
C;30;40;0
x;5;15;1
y;15;25;1
z;25;35;1
```

I'm reading the file with pandas, group the data and then iterate through the data. Within each group, I want to iterate through the rows of the data set:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("samples_test.csv", delimiter=";", header=0)

groups = df.groupby("set")
for name, group in groups:
    somestuff = [group["N_D"], group["mu"], name]

    for i, txt in enumerate(group["Name"]):
        print(txt, group["Name"][i])
```

The code fails on the line `print(txt, group["Name"][i])` at the first element of the second group with an key error. I don't understand, why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fails since the series index does not match with the enumerator index for each loop hence cannot match the keys for filtering, (*Note: Also use .loc[] or .iloc[] and avoid [chained indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) `group["Name"][i]`*)

```
groups = df.groupby("set")
for name, group in groups:
    somestuff = [group["N_D"], group["mu"], name]

    for i, txt in enumerate(group["Name"]):
        print(i,group["Name"])
```

---

```
0 0    A
  1    B
  2    C
Name: Name, dtype: object
1 0    A
  1    B
  2    C
.......
....
```

Your code should be changed to below using [`.iloc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and [`get_loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for getting the column index:

```
groups = df.groupby("set")
for name, group in groups:
    somestuff = [group["N_D"], group["mu"], name]
    for i, txt in enumerate(group["Name"]):
        print(txt,group.iloc[i,group.columns.get_loc('Name')])
```

---

```
A A
B B
C C
x x
y y
z z
```